# Python: Pass ContexVars from parent thread to child thread spawn using threading.Thread()

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, threadpool, python-contextvars

I am setting some context variables using `contextvars` module that can be accessed across the modules running on the same thread.
Initially I was creating `contextvars.ContextVars()` object in each python file hoping that there is only single context shared amongts all the python files of the module running on same thread. But for each file it did create new context variables.

I took inspiration from flask library how it sets context of the web request in request object so that only thread on which web request came will be able to access it. Resources: (1) [Request Contex working in flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/reqcontext/) (2) [Flask Contexts advance](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-contexts-advanced/)

Basically, the **Local** class below is copy pasted from **werkzeug** library (werkzeug.local module : https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/local/#werkzeug.local.Local)

**customContextObject.py**

```
from contextvars import ContextVar
import typing as t
import warnings

class Local:
    __slots__ = ("_storage",)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        object.__setattr__(self, "_storage", ContextVar("local_storage"))

    @property
    def __storage__(self) -> t.Dict[str, t.Any]:
        warnings.warn(
            "'__storage__' is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 2.1.",
            DeprecationWarning,
            stacklevel=2,
        )
        return self._storage.get({})  # type: ignore

    def __iter__(self) -> t.Iterator[t.Tuple[int, t.Any]]:
        return iter(self._storage.get({}).items())

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> t.Any:
        values = self._storage.get({})
        try:
            print(f"_storage : {self._storage} | values : {values}")
            return values[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name) from None

    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: t.Any) -> None:
        values = self._storage.get({}).copy()
        values[name] = value
        self._storage.set(values)

    def __delattr__(self, name: str) -> None:
        values = self._storage.get({}).copy()
        try:
            del values[name]
            self._storage.set(values)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name) from None

localContextObject = Local()
```

The `localContextObject` know can be imported in any python file in the project and they will have access to same ContextVar object.

Example: I am setting email property in localContextObject variable in **contextVARSDifferentModulesCUSTOM.py** file **contextVARSexperiments** module. We import and call check_true_false() function from **utils.py**

```
from contextVARSexperiments.utils import check_true_false, check_true_false
from contextVARSexperiments.customContextObject import localContextObject
import threading

localContextObject.email = "example@email.com"
print(f"localContextObject : {localContextObject} | email : {localContextObject.email}")


def callingUtils(a):
    print(f"{threading.current_thread()} | {threading.main_thread()}")
    check_true_false(a)


callingUtils('MAIN CALL')
```

Now the other file **utils.py** in the same module will have access to the same contextVars through localContextObject. It will print the same email as set in above file.

**utils.py**

```
import threading
import contextvars
from contextVARSexperiments.customContextObject import localContextObject


def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("\n~~~ENTERING check_true_false~~~~~~ ")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("~~~EXITED check_true_false~~~~~~\n")
    return wrapper


@decorator
def check_true_false(a):
    print(f"check_true_false2 {threading.current_thread()} | {threading.main_thread()}")
    print(f" a : {a}")
    print(f"localContextObject : {localContextObject}")
    print(f"email : {localContextObject.email}")
```

Below is the output when we run contextVARSDifferentModulesCUSTOM.py

```
/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/Temp/contextVARSexperiments/contextVARSDifferentModulesCUSTOM.py 
localContextObject : <_thread._local object at 0x7fcfb85fdd58> | email : example@email.com
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 8671015616)> | <_MainThread(MainThread, started 8671015616)>
~~~ENTERING check_true_false~~~~~~ 
check_true_false <_MainThread(MainThread, started 8671015616)> | <_MainThread(MainThread, started 8671015616)>
 a : MAIN CALL
localContextObject : <_thread._local object at 0x7fcfb85fdd58>
email : example@email.com
~~~EXITED check_true_false~~~~~~
```

Now, I updated contextVARSDifferentModulesCUSTOM.py  to call callingUtils() function on a **new thread**.

```
from contextVARSexperiments.utils import check_true_false
from contextVARSexperiments.customContextObject import localContextObject
import threading

localContextObject.email = "example@email.com"
print(f"localContextObject : {localContextObject} | email : {localContextObject.email}")


def callingUtils(a):
    print(f"{threading.current_thread()} | {threading.main_thread()}")
    check_true_false(a)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=callingUtils, args=('THREAD"S CALL',))
t1.start()
t1.join()
```

But this threw error because child thread didn't have access to parent thread's ContextVars. Output:

```
/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/Temp/contextVARSexperiments/contextVARSDifferentModulesCUSTOM.py 
_storage : <ContextVar name='local_storage' at 7ff1d0435668> | values : {'email': 'example@email.com'}
localContextObject : <contextVARSexperiments.customContextObject.Local object at 0x7ff1c02162e8> | email : example@email.com
<Thread(Thread-1, started 12937875456)> | <_MainThread(MainThread, started 8609043136)>

~~~ENTERING check_true_false~~~~~~ 
check_true_false <Thread(Thread-1, started 12937875456)> | <_MainThread(MainThread, started 8609043136)>
 a : THREAD"S CALL
localContextObject : <contextVARSexperiments.customContextObject.Local object at 0x7ff1c02162e8>
_storage : <ContextVar name='local_storage' at 7ff1d0435668> | values : {}
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/Temp/contextVARSexperiments/contextVARSDifferentModulesCUSTOM.py", line 13, in callingUtils
    check_true_false(a)
  File "/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/Temp/contextVARSexperiments/utils.py", line 26, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/Temp/contextVARSexperiments/utils.py", line 43, in check_true_false
    print(f"email : {localContextObject.email}")
  File "/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/Temp/contextVARSexperiments/customContextObject.py", line 31, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: email
```

Now, I am trying to inherit Thread class and create my own custom implementation which will pass the context from parent thread to child thread.

I tried to replace `threading.Thread` class with a `CustomThread` class. Following are the implementations of `CustomThread` class inside **customThreading.py** :

More about `Context` object returned by `copy_context()` method of contextvars library : https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#contextvars.Context

1. Using `Context` object returned by `copy_context()` to run initialiser of Threading class:

```
    import threading
    import contextvars
    
    class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.current_context = contextvars.copy_context()
            self.current_context.run(super().__init__, *args, **kwargs)
    
        def start(self) -> None:
            super().start()
```

2. Using `Context` object returned by `copy_context()` while calling `start()` of Threading class:

```
    import threading
    import contextvars
    
    class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.current_context = contextvars.copy_context()
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        def start(self) -> None:
            self.current_context.run(super().start)
```

3. Using `contextmanager` decorator from **contextlib** on `start()` of my class:

```
    import threading
    import contextvars
    from contextlib import contextmanager
    
    class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.current_context = contextvars.copy_context()
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        @contextmanager
        def start(self) -> None:
            super().start()
```

But none of this worked.

Also, I am looking for custom implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contextvars work similar as `threading.local` variables, in that, in each thread, a context var is initially empty. It can take further independent values in the same thread by using the `context.run`  method from a `contextvars.Context` object, and that is extensively used by the asyncio code, so that each call-stack in a asyncio task can have an independent context in a transparent way.

The code you picked from werkzeug automatically creates an empty dictionary when the context var used as storage is read - so you get the errors you listed, instead of a `LookupError`.

Anyway, I digress - the only thing incorrect in your code is that `start` is not the function to override in order to change the running context: it is called in the parent thread.

The `run` method in the Thread class is the one that is executed in the child thread - if you just override that one so that it executes the code in the original `run` method inside your passed context, you will get things working:

```
class CTXThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def run(self):
        # This code runs in the target, child class:
        self.ctx.run(super().run)
```

Also, as a side note, see that the `contextlib` module, and the `contextmanager` decorator, are not related to contextvars *at all*.  Python re-uses the term "context" for more than one thing - in the case "contextlib" refers to context managers as used by the `with` statement.

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno for explaining. Any pointers you can give if I have to implement similar requirement for threads created using ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures module.

Comment: Do you care posting a similar question to this one, adding that you want that with concurrent.Futures? 

I will be happy to answer that when I come to check "fun questions" later on. It will require some more customization anyway.  (The first thing I can thing about is a decorator to be applied on the functions that will run in the PoolExecutor workers)

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno for the initial directions. I might be starting working on it soon. I will post a similar question if I face some challenges after trying myself. Thank you again for sharing your thoughts here!